# Find Permutations of String in Scala

Tags: strings, scala

> Given a smaller strings and a bigger string b, design an algorithm to find all permuta­tions of the shorter string within the longer one.

```
def findPermutations(large: String, small: String): Int =         
    large.sliding(small.length).filter(_.diff(small).isEmpty).length

@ findPermutations("cbabadcbbabbcbabaabccbabc", "abbc") 
res11: Int = 7

@ findPermutations("xaabx", "abb") 
res12: Int = 0
```

### Archived (faulty)

```
@ def findPermutations(large: String, small: String): Int = 
  large.sliding(small.length)
       .toList
       .filter(_.toSet == small.toSet)
       .length 
defined function findPermutations
```

Please evaluate it for correctness and speed.

Comment: Algorithm is faulty: `findPermutations("xaabx", "abb")` and the `.toList` doesn't serve any useful purpose.

Comment: Thanks, @jwvh. Please check out my update!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **correct** - As far as I can tell, yes.
- **concise** - A `filter()` followed by a `.length` (or `.size`) can be simplified:
  `large.sliding(small.length).count(_.diff(small).isEmpty)`
- **fast** - Could be faster, but it wouldn't be as concise.

Consider the following: `findPermutations("abcxcba", "cab")`

Under the current design that would be 5 invocations of `_.diff(small).isEmpty`, but 3 of the 5 are rather pointless. No test string containing a character not found in the target string is worth the effort.

It'd be nice if the sliding window could "jump" over non-target characters. Doable, but not trivial.